# How to use Facebook api v2.6?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to integrate the latest `Facebook` `API` v2.6. I don't have any idea how to implement it in the application.

```
 login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            /* make the API call */
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "me?fields=email,name,last_name,id,first_name",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        //Getting Error Here

                                Log.d("JSON", "" + response.getJSONObject().toString());
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        }
    });
}
```

I am getting this error on the callback.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.facebookLive.FacebookLiveActivity$1.onCompleted(FacebookLiveActivity.java:89)
```

Comment: create a new app, it will automatically use the current latest version. not sure what your question is though...

Comment: I don’t see what that error message has to do with the API version ... All of the fields you are asking for existed in previous API versions already.

Comment: @CBroe if that is not the problem, is there any problem in my syntax?

Comment: No, then you would get a different error, resp. the whole thing would not even run to begin with. You have a NullPointerException, menaing your are trying to access properties/methods of an object that is just Null. Since it mentions the onCompleted handler, I’d assume that your debug output line is the problem, `response.getJSONObject().toString()` – if response is Null, that would give you that error. So log the response object to console directly, and see what it contains (likely an error message from the API.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

            final JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();



            try {
                if(json != null){

                    Log.e(TAG, json.getString("name"));
                    Log.e(TAG, json.getString("email"));
                    Log.e(TAG, json.getString("id"));






            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: this is not the latest api version.

Comment: how you decide this not latest version api ?

Comment: look for the graph request method

Comment: @user6071487 bro  there are many way to get data from facebook  login and it means not this old api